# Format a 1 form with 2 different css class

Tags: html, css, forms

I am new on here and would really appreciate some help, I am trying to format an input form with css however the the form has a text area that I need to format to the same as the rest of the form.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<div id="login">
<h2>Data Archive</h2>
<hr/>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>HDD Name  :</label>
<input type="text" name="hdd_name" id="hdd_name" required="required"     placeholder="Please enter HDD name"/><br /><br />
<label>Date Archived  :</label>
<input type="text" name="date_archived" id="date_archived" required="required"  placeholder="Date data was archived"/><br/><br />
<label>Project Name  :</label>
<input type="text" name="project_name" id="project_name" required="required"  placeholder="Project name"/><br/><br />
<label>Client  :</label>
<input type="text" name="client" id="client" required="required"  placeholder="Client name"/><br/><br />
<label>Archived by  :</label>
<input type="text" name="archived_by" id="archived_by" required="required"  placeholder="Name of person archiving data"/><br/><br />
<label>Editor  :</label>
<input type="text" name="editor" id="editor" required="required"  placeholder="Editor name"/><br/><br />
<label>Other information  :</label>
<div class="textarea"><textarea name="other_information" id="other_information" wrap="virtual"/>Any other information</textarea><br/><br />    </div>
<input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit"/><br />
</form>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
textarea{
width: 290px;
height: 75px;
border-radius: 10px;
font-family:raleway;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

#login{
width:300px;
float: left;
border-radius: 10px;
font-family:raleway;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
padding: 10px 40px 25px;
margin-top: 70px;
}
```

Really hoping you can shed some light on this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give each item that you want to be the same a CSS class.

```
<input class="mytextboxes" type="text" ... />
<textarea class="mytextboxes" name="other_information" ... />Any other information</textarea>
```

Then you can use the CSS class like this:

```
.mytextboxes{
  /* styling here */
}
```

Here's a tutorial from W3 schools to get you started.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do the styling of inputs of type by using a CSS like this.

```
input[type="text"] {
  /* Your styles*/
}
```